# Looking for a function that searches for nodes

Tags: nodes

Is there a function in Drupal-7 that looks or searches for nodes that match some criteria (e.g. promoted nodes, published nodes, nodes of a specific content type), rather than using Views?

Comment: There isn't a single core function that can replace Views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing that you get is [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7), which will allow you to construct a query that will yield the nodes that match the conditions.